# How to unhide the hidden application in mac os programmatically?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, show-hide

I want to unhide the hidden applications in mac os . For hiding I am using this  `[ [ NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace ] hideOtherApplications ];`

[image: Something like this]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's several ways to unhide all hidden apps — here are a couple of them:

**NSWorkspace**:

```
NSMutableArray *arr = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

for (NSRunningApplication *app in [[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] runningApplications]) {
    [app unhide];
}
```

...or...

**NSApplication**:

```
- (void) unhideAllApplications:(id)sender{
    [NSApp unhideAllApplications:sender];
}
```

and call with something like:

```
[self unhideAllApplications:nil];
```